# Alternative to NetworkInfo.isConnected() (Deprecated in API 23) for Network objects

Tags: java, android

I want to use `ConnectivityManager` to check if an active network can access the internet or not ie. `getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()`.

I read that we can still use `getActiveNetwork()` to get an active network, but there doesn't seem to be a similar method like `isConnected` for `Network` objects. How to workaround?

The deprecated code is found here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-asynctask-asynctaskloader/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#4

Comment: Note that "connected" is not "can access the internet"

Comment: @RyanM So what is the alternative to isConnected() if i want to use Network object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check the connectivity. **connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()** is added in SDK 29.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    if (context == null) return false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return info != null && info.isConnected();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: According to the docs `getActiveNetwork()` was added in API level 23.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use new implementation for SDK_INT >= Q and for older versions you use old api and suppress deprecation like this:

In kotlin:

```
val Context.isNetworkConnected: Boolean
    get() {
        val manager = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        return if (SDK_INT >= Q)
            manager.getNetworkCapabilities(manager.activeNetwork)?.let {
                it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI) || it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                        it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) ||
                        it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) ||
                        it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_VPN)
            } ?: false
        else
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            manager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected == true
    }
```

Comment: You use new implementation for SDK_INT >= Q and for older versions you use old api and suppress deprecation ... tell me what is not ok here ?

Comment: my bad. I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkInfo` deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo

- `getActiveNetworkInfo` deprecated on API 29.
- `getAllNetworkInfo` deprecated on API 23.

You should use this code.

```kotlin
   private fun isAvailableNetwork(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val networkCapabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network) ?: return false
        return when {
            networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }
```